# Reliable code for automatic \noindent after specific environments?

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs, patching

> **This question led to a new package:**
> [`noindentafter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/noindentafter)

There are a number of environments which I never want to follow up with an indented paragraph. `itemize`, `enumerate`, `theorem`, `definition`, etc. I know there are people who [think](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/should-i-place-noindent-after-enumerations-itemization-and-descriptions) this is bad style. But it's a personal preference. Those environments basically always end a paragraph for me, so the visual clue is not needed in my case.

I've found several similar questions, but none of them do what I need:

- [Automatic \noindent on the first paragraph of each theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42692/automatic-noindent-on-the-first-paragraph-of-each-theorem-environment)
- [Automatically adding \noindent after \section{*}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61640/automatically-adding-noindent-after-section)
- [Automatic noindent after quote environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/automatic-noindent-after-quote-environment)

That third one was actually most useful, but appears to be unreliable for patching existing environments with. It doesn't seem to be working in my `memoir` document.

To be clear, I don't want to remove the actual paragraph break. That's a semantic concept. I just want to patch the document style so that paragraphs following certain environments remain unindented.

I've tried the following two 'solutions' (which use `etoolbox` for patching):

```
\newcommand*{\noindentnext}{\everypar{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}\everypar{}}}
\newcommand*{\NoIndentAfterEnv}[1]{\AfterEndEnvironment{#1}{\noindentnext}}
\newcommand*{\NoIndentAfterCmd}[1]{\apptocmd{#1}{\noindentnext}{}{}}

\NoIndentAfterEnv{itemize}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{theorem}
...
```

This one is loosely based on the third post from the list above. It sometimes works. It sometimes does nothing. I'm unable to predict when it will fail. The second:

```
\let\old@par\par
\newcommand*{\noindentnextpar}{\def\par{\let\par\old@par\par\noindent}}
\newcommand*{\NoParIndentAfterEnv}[1]{\AfterEndEnvironment{#1}{\noindentnextpar}}
\newcommand*{\NoParIndentAfterCmd}[1]{\apptocmd{#1}{\noindentnextpar}{}{}}
```

I invented this one myself. It breaks when the patched environment is *not* followed by a paragraph. It has also shown itself to inexplicably fail in other situations.

Once and for all, I'd like to have a reliable way to do this.

Let me give an example of what I need, just to be clear:

```
\NoIndentAfterEnv{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
    \item ...
\end{itemize}

This starts a new paragraph. Note the empty line. But it should not be indented.

But this paragraph \emph{should} be indented.
```

Comment: Sorry my first attempt was a big flaw. I tried `\newcommand*{\noindentnext}{\def\par{\@@par\noindent\let\par\@@par}}` but you have the same. What do you mean it breaks?

Comment: Well, I'm not *exactly* sure. But I remember that I had to be careful in a lot of situations or I'd get errors. An example: I get a `missing \item` error if a `proof` environment *ends* while the augmented `\par` is still in effect. I also remember getting errors if several augmented environments followed each other without a paragraph inbetween, but I can't seem to reproduce this right now.

Comment: I've made the following rather invasive patch to fix these errors: `\let\@old@end\end\renewcommand{\end}[1]{\let\par\@@par\@old@end{#1}}`. Seems like I shouldn't be able to get away with it, but I did.

Comment: FWIW, ConTeXt provides an `indentnext` key to control the indentation after an environment. See [this article](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Indentation#Setting_up_indentation_after_an_environment) on ConTeXt wiki for details. This is an old feature that works with MkII (pdftex/xetex) as well as MkIV (luatex).

Comment: The `noindentafter` package is broken with the latest latex version (may 2021), seems it has been broken since nov 2019. See [this github issue](https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-noindentafter/pull/3) and [this SE TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514127/incompatibility-between-noindentafter-and-etoolbox-v2-5f) question for details and potential solutions.

Comment: The package has been updated on CTAN and is obviously working again so I removed the edit again.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could make the following paragraph believe that it follows a heading where there's also no indent by appending `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading` after the end of the environment. Package [`etoolbox`](http://www.cta.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides the handy `\AfterEndEnvironment` which makes this an easy task. `\@afterheading` also temporarily sets `\clubpenalty` to `\@M` (10000), though. If you don't want this after the patched environment one could insert an adapted version of `\@afterheading` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
% environment hooks and patching:
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% uncomment the following if you don't want \clubpenalty\@M ...
% \let\nearly@afterheading\@afterheading
% \patchcmd\nearly@afterheading
%   {\@M}% original temporary setting for \clubpenalty replaced by ...
%   {\@clubpenalty}% ... or whichever value you deem right
%   {}{}
% ... and use \nearly@afterheading instead of \@afterheading here:
\newcommand*\NoIndentAfterEnv[1]{%
  \AfterEndEnvironment{#1}{\par\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}}
\makeatother

\NoIndentAfterEnv{itemize}
% treat other environments you want to patch accordingly

% dummy text:
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{itemize}
  \item foo
  \item bar
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Pretty short! :-) It seems to work as expected in all cases that I could come up with. Furthermore, page breaks still seem to be allowed at the point of patching (why did you think they wouldn't be?) --- If there's one thing that keeps this solution from being perfect, it's the fact that the semantic distinction of paragraph breaks is now lost. A paragraph break is now applied even where I don't insert an empty line. This might affect documents that do other stuff at paragraph breaks. --- But that's just nitpicking. This solution will be just fine!

Comment: »A paragraph break is now applied even where I don't insert an empty line.« -- But didn't you say _Those environments basically always end a paragraph for me_, anyway? ;)

Comment: BTW: I'm not sure if the `\clubpenalty\@M` actually has any unwanted effects or not but I still wanted to point it out.

Comment: Ah, that was just to get the typography nazis off my back. ;-) Neh... it's actually true in my case, so the imperfection doesn't bother me, except on a conceptual level.

Comment: I just noticed that *both* you and I received Revival badges for this question. Nice bug, isn't it?

Comment: @lockstep that's funny... well, badges, who knows what they're good for, anyway ;)

Comment: @cgnieder By the way, I'd like to write a small package around this and submit it to CTAN, unless you want to do it yourself.

Comment: @mhelvens that was only a one-liner... hardly enough for a package, isn't it? But go ahead :) (I'm maintaining too many packages already!)

Comment: @cgnieder It's a useful contribution nonetheless. I've been searching for something like this for over half a year. :-) I'd probably have found it if it was on CTAN with a name like `noindentafter`. --- And the fact that it's short is the only reason I have time to write it. ;-)

Comment: There, package finished. Until it is available on CTAN, you can find the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/latex-noindentafter/source/browse/tags/0.0.1-r2).

Comment: I think this is not quite robust as it changes the spacing if the `\end{itemize}` is immediately followed with a new section/subsection.

Comment: @Jörg that may be true, I haven't tested it. If I find the time I may add something to this respect

Comment: That would be great :-).

Comment: Without looking more closely at this: Obviously the package `noindentafter` takes care of the problem observed by @Jörg

Comment: @Florian it was developed as a result of this question and its answer so that might well be ;)

Comment: @cgnieder I am aware of that ;) I was referring to the observation from Apr 30 '14 at 14:44 that the vertical spacing of sectioning-commands directly after a patched environment is affected by your initial code. This problem was obviously tackled by the package-author as it produces identical vertical spacing in these cases, while there'll be ca .5ex shifting for your code.

Comment: Uisng TeXlive2023, lualatex, with a custom document class (no lists, no items): The `noindentafter`package may not work properly in some usage situations. So far, the @cgnieder code always works for me. Certainly usage-dependent.

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to unconditionally remove indentation after list environments (note that quotes and theorems are also based on `list`) seems to be to change the definition of `\@doendpe`, specifically, to remove the code where *"`\par` is redefined to restore `\everypar`"* ([source2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf)). See [What exactly does \@doendpe do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/what-exactly-does-doendpe-do) for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\makeatletter
\def\@doendpe{%
  \@endpetrue
%  \def\par{% REMOVED
%    \@restorepar% REMOVED
%    \everypar{}% REMOVED
%    \par% REMOVED
%    \@endpefalse% REMOVED
%  }% REMOVED
  \everypar{%
    {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
    \everypar{}%
    \@endpefalse
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sometext

\begin{itemize}
\item \sometext
\end{itemize}

\sometext

\begin{quote}
\sometext
\end{quote}

\sometext

\begin{theorem}
\sometext
\end{theorem}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Should you want to remove indentation only after specific list-based (!) environments, you can incorporate a new `\noindentafter` switch into `\@doendpe` and use `etoolbox`' `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` to set the switch to true for the respective environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\newif\ifnoindentafter
\noindentafterfalse

\makeatletter
\def\@doendpe{%
  \@endpetrue
  \ifnoindentafter% ADDED
  \else% ADDED
    \def\par{%
      \@restorepar
      \everypar{}
      \par
      \@endpefalse
      \noindentafterfalse% ADDED
    }%
  \fi% ADDED
  \everypar{%
    {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
    \everypar{}%
    \@endpefalse
    \noindentafterfalse% ADDED
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\noindentaftertrue}

\begin{document}

\sometext

\begin{itemize}
\item \sometext
\end{itemize}

\sometext

\begin{enumerate}
\item \sometext
\end{enumerate}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: good try, but it doesn't work with `amsthm`.  (although that isn't exactly what was requested.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know that the AMS classes are special: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36835/510

Comment: @lockstep Great solution! It makes a lot of sense to take away the code that inserts the indentation rather than to add extra code to remove it again. And I see you even made it selective now! --- However, there are two reasons why I'm going with cgnieders solution: (1) It applies to any environment or command I want; not just list-based environments and (2) it's so much shorter and less invasive. --- Nonetheless, I found your answer very instructive.

Comment: @mhelvens I was aware of (1), but since all your example environments were based on `list`, I decided to write an answer anyway.

Comment: @lockstep You're right. But as it happens, there's one command I still wanted to patch: `\]` :-)