# Better idiomatic way to print a centered "starlet" (asterisk)?

Tags: code-review

I need to print what the publisher calls "a starlet" (asterisk).

I devised the code below, but I am not sure if it is a sound code, i.e., it won't cause problems later on, within other commands and the text stream.

Is that the idiomatic way to print a special character (in this case, `mathabx`'s `\varstar`), centered and with 1 blank line above and below?

I am using `\vgrid` in order to check the vertical alignment is preserved as precisely as possible, in respect to the underlying grid.

```
\documentclass[
DIV=calc,
twoside,
openright,
twocolumn=false,
titlepage,
numbers=noenddot,
headinclude=true,
footinclude=true,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\newcommand{\aster}{$\varstar$} 

\usepackage{vgrid}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\starlet}{% 
  \par
  \vskip -0.5pt
  \noindent
  \parbox{\linewidth}{
    \begin{center}
      \aster
    \end{center}
  }
  \par
  \vskip 0.6pt % make it fit the grid
  \noindent
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\starlet
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would try to avoid the use of `\vskip` if at all possible.  See also [`fourier-orns`](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/fonts/fourier-GUT/doc/latex/fourier/fourier-orns.pdf)

Comment: @sean-allred Thank you. I need to use precisely the `\varstar` symbol. I did not see that in `fourier-orns`. I am using `vskip` in order to precisely align the text to the grid. Try to remove it, and you will see the difference. Is there a safer alternative?

Comment: The LaTeX version of `\vskip` is `\vspace` … see my answer below.

Comment: As shown in the answers below, you need to not put the vertical spacing into a box, otherwise you will get very bad behaviour at a page break with anomalous white space not being dropped (at a page break your negative vskip would be discarded but the space that it was correcting, from the center environment would be kept as it is inside the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using `\centering` instead of `{center}` since the former adds no vertical space and let’s you control the spacing exactly it without the need of fiddling with corrections. To use `\centering` only for a part of your document enclose it in a group, i.e. `{…}`, and add a `\par` after it but *inside* the group. Then use `\(add)vspace` with `\baselineskip` as value to add blank lines before and after.

```
\usepackage{adjustbox,noindentafter}

\newcommand{\starlet}{%
  {% 
    \par
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}%
    \centering
    \adjustbox{raise=1pt}{\aster}%
    \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  }%
  \NoIndentAfterThis
}
```

**Some notes**

- `\addvspace` chacks wether there is already some space before and adds it only when necessary. At the of the definition you can use the normal `\vspace` since there won't be any space before it.
- `\NoIndentAfterThis` (needs `noindentafter`) is the way to prevent the indent after the command. This must be outside of the group. (see [Reliable code for automatic \noindent after specific environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112404/4918))
- If you want to center `\aster` in the line, one way is to use `\adjustbox{raise=1pt}{\aster}` (needs `adjustbox`) or another way is `\raisbox{1pt}{\aster}` (needs `graphicx`).
- The `\makeatletter/other` pair isn’t needed here since you don’t use commands containing `@` as part of their name.

---

To center a single line (box) one can also use `\hspace` with `\fill` as a value:

```
\newcommand{\starletII}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\baselineskip}%
  \hspace*{\fill}% without the star space would be ignored it it
         % begins/ends a line
  \adjustbox{raise=1pt}{$\star$}%
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \NoIndentAfterThis
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. The second paragraph remains centered and indented. How can I make it  fully justified and with no indentation, like my original (primitive) code?

Comment: My fault. I forgot to add the group. It is fixed in the code above already (doubled braces at the begin/end of definition) …

Comment: If you leave a trailing `\noindent` (anywhere) you will live to regret it:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Why? If the following line shouldn’t be indented in all cases. Your welcome to change my definition in an appropriate way to no-indent the following line ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Then, how can one automatically define the following paragraph as without indentation, as I need to do?

Comment: I guess this is the way to go: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112404/4918

Comment: It prematurely starts the next paragraph, so if what follows is a vertical thing eg a list or a heading or a ... or even just a blank line then you will get an anomolous white line from a paragraph that contains nothing.  I'd just delete the `\noindent` but if you want to make it suppress indentation it should work like a section heading or `\item` and use the `\@afterheading` mechanism

Comment: @tobi: Thank you for pointing out `noindentafter`. And thank you for the answer!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was having the feeling my original code was going to be troublesome somewhere. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: :-) thanks. But maybe you can explain something strange, please? With the above definition an `{itemize}` `\item` following the `\starlet` is on the right vertical position (i.e. the next grid line with one line space above) but when I remove `\NoIndentAfterThis` the `\item` adds more space and goes to a wrong position  … why?

Answer (score 2):

(Answer updated to incorporate the fact that use of `\varstar`, rather than of some arbitrary asterisk symbol, is required.)

I suppose an idiomatic LaTeXy way of creating a blank line of height `\baselineskip` is to type `\par\null\par`. To center-set a given symbol, one could use the TeX "primitive" command `\centerline`. In the code below, the command `\starlet` sandwiches the instruction `\centerline{$\varstar$}` between two sets of `\par\null\par` instructions. The total height of the output generated by `\starlet` is exactly `3\baselineskip`, automatically preserving any grid alignment that may be in place.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}  % for \varstar symbol

\newcommand\starlet{%
  \par\null\par%  a blank line of height \baselineskip
  \centerline{$\varstar$}%  center-set the ask
  \par\null\par}% another blank line of height \baselineskip

%% Just for this example:
  \setlength\parindent{0pt} 
  \usepackage[textwidth=2.95in,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Some meaningless fluff.

Some meaningless fluff.

Some meaningless fluff.

Some meaningless fluff.

Some meaningless fluff.

\newpage  % induce a column break
Some meaningless fluff.

\starlet

Some meaningless fluff.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. `\textasteriskcentered` is nice, but the publisher requested the `\varstar` symbol to be used (they are slightly different asterisks)

Comment: @gsl - Sorry, I had missed the fact that usage of the `\varstar` symbol was a requirement. I've updated the code to incorporate this information.

Comment: But wouldn’t @DavidCarlisle’s comment, that we get in trouble when something like `{itemize}` follows, apply here too?

Comment: @Tobi - Maybe I'm dense, but I don't "get" this concern. In my experience, "starlets" only ever occur in running text, with a paragraph both preceding and following the "starlet". I don't think one has to worry too much about a "vertical thing" (David's expression, not mine!) occurring immediately after a starlet. Single or multiple blank lines following my version of `\starlet` are actually OK, as my MWE shows... Maybe the OP will weigh in and communicate how he/she intends to use the "starlets"?

Comment: @Tobi - Another reason I think one doesn't have to worry about "vertical things" in the present context is that the OP has mentioned explicitly that he/she is trying to get typesetting on a grid going. I would therefore expect that the OP has already redefined `\par` to eliminate any stretchability and shrinkability.

Comment: I share your experience, that starlets are used kind of exclusively in normal paragraph contexts, but I wanted to add a note on this for sake of completeness ;-)