# Suppress paragraph indentation after tcblisting environment?

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs, tcolorbox

I am writing a document containing lost of snippets of code, and I've defined an environment using `tcblisting` from the `tcolorbox` package to do this.  The environments work fine.

What I want to do though is to suppress paragraph indentation afterwards so that

```
\begin{mycode}
   lots of stuff using my environment
\end{mycode}

which shows that Santa Claus \emph{does} exist,\ldots
```

has the effect of *not* indenting "which shows that..."  I understand that the `after` parameter is what I need here; this is described in the `tcolorbox` manual (for v3.12) in section 3.12 (page 62).  However, I can't get the result I want; for example `after={\par\baselineskip\parindent=0pt}` doesn't work.

I can go through and put a `\noindent` at all the places, but surely there's a way I can do it in the environment definition itself?

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide some code we can compile, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? It'll get you answers much faster than providing code-snippets.

Comment: A blank line is a paragraph break.

Comment: With a blank line before the text you are signalling a new paragraph. If you do not put a blank line there then latex environments such as `verbatim` or `enumerate` would not indent the text. It appears tcblisting doesn't implement that which is a shame, but Harish's answer provides a workaround

Comment: Yes, I think using a blank line and expecting no indentation is asking a bit much, so Harish's approach, with a % for readability, seems the way to go.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112404/

Answer (score 6):

Use `after={\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent}` and then

```
\end{code}
which shows that Santa Claus \emph{does} exist,\ldots
```

(no blank line after `\end{code}`) or

```
\end{code}
%
which shows that Santa Claus \emph{does} exist,\ldots
```

if you need that blank for readability.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\newtcblisting{code}[1][]{
  width=\linewidth,
  enhanced,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colback=light-gray,
  listing only,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=python,
    showstringspaces=false,
  },
  after={\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent}  %% do you really need \vspace{\baselineskip}?
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{code}
for i in range(n):
    print('i = ', i)
\end{code}
%
which shows that Santa Claus \emph{does} exist,\ldots    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!  I think I was in error expecting a black line with no indentation; I will take your advice and put a % sign there for readability, as well as adjusting my `after=` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A bit old, but as I just thought about this problem in another context. You can try this to suppress the parindent even if there is an empty line after the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\let\@oridoenpe\@doendpe
\def\@newdoendpe{%
     \@endpetrue
     \def\par{\@restorepar\global\let\@doendpe\@oridoenpe
              \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
              \everypar
               {{\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
                \everypar{}}\par\@endpefalse}%
     \everypar{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
                \everypar{}\@restorepar\@endpefalse
               }}

\newcommand\usenewdoendpe{\global\let\@doendpe\@newdoendpe}
\newcommand\useendparenv{\par\@endparenv}
\makeatother

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\newtcblisting{code}[1][]{
  after={\usenewdoendpe\smallskip\useendparenv}  %% 
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{code}
for i in range(n):
    print('i = ', i)
\end{code}

which shows that Santa Claus \emph{does} exist,\ldots

\begin{code}
for i in range(n):
    print('i = ', i)
\end{code}
which shows that Santa Claus \emph{does} exist,\ldots


\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

It won't work for breakable boxes (even if they are not broken).