# Noindentafter package not working after first paragraph

Tags: indentation

I'm new with LaTeX. I'm having problem with indentation after `{enumerate}`. I search and got [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112404/reliable-code-for-automatic-noindent-after-specific-environments) which led to [noindentafter](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/noindentafter?lang=en) package. Somewhat it's not working on the second paragraph after the enumeration.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{noindentafter}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{enumerate}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Hello World!}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante.

\end{document}
```

Here's the result

[image]

I was expecting the second and third paragraphs after the enumeration should not have indentation.

Adding `\noindent` before those two paragraphs solve the problem, but I'm looking for more automatic way. How should I do that?

Comment: You're reading wrongly the manual: the *first* paragraph after `enumerate` will have no indent.

Comment: I'm sorry I just read the description: "au­to­mat­i­cally sup­press in­den­ta­tions in **fol­low­ing para­graphs**". So how to automatically suppress second, third, so on paragraphs?

Comment: Bad wording, I'd say: the paragraphs that immediately follow `enumerate` (the environment you specify in `\NoIndentAfterEnv`) are not indented. When should the “no indentation” stop, otherwise? In my opinion you should follow the standard: if you don't want the indent, don't leave an empty line. Take into account that the indent is very important for the reader.

Comment: @PetraBarus when you want no paragraph indents *at all* then do not use the `noindentafter` package but use the `parskip` package instead.

Comment: Note: the `noindentafter` package is broken with the latest latex version (may 2021), seems it has been broken since nov 2019. See [this github issue](https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-noindentafter/pull/3) and [this SE TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514127/incompatibility-between-noindentafter-and-etoolbox-v2-5f) question for details and potential solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description on CTAN is a bit misleading. There is no appearance of “paragraphs” in the manual. What the package does is suppressing the indentation for the *next* paragraph following the declared environments. To be honest, also the documentation may be misleading.

Here is a shorter description: if you do `\NoIndentAfterEnv{enumerate}`, leaving a blank line or not after `\end{enumerate}` will produce the same output.

Besides, where should the “no indentation” stop? If you want to suppress the indentation in *all* paragraphs, consider the `parskip` package.

Comment: Thanks! Package `parskip` is what I'm looking for!